# Pass parameter to webservice with .xml extension

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am creating an application in which i have made web services using cakephp. I have one web service named http://demo.narolainfotech.com/remindz/users/login.xml and in controller folder there is one web service called UserController.php in which login and registration functions are written. When i am putting static value in this web service and parse this file i am getting data for logged in user properly but when i am passing parameter from xcode the Post data is not getting parsed.php code print_r($_POST); it's displaying blank array. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

My Code is :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",URL_Login];
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<login xmlns=\"\">"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<user_email>%@</user_email>",@"raaaavai123_dholakiya@yahoo.co.in"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<passWord>%@</passWord>",@"dholakiya"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</login>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(con)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"the Connection is NULL");
}
```

}

Comment: instead of screenshot can you post the code here ? it will help full to Answer your Question.